# Swift - Handling Firebase Timestamp

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I am working on firebase project, I have Timestamp field in a Collection, which looks below image

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giWB0.png)

When I read that time stamp from **Indian time zone**, I am getting date string as **Sun Jan 26, 2020 12:00 AM**

But When I read it from **Pago Pago - American Samoa(GMT-11) time Zone**, I am getting date string as **Sat Jan 25, 2020 07:30 AM**

I am using below code

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"
    let coll = Firestore.firestore().collection("Collection1")
    coll.getDocuments { (snap, error) in
        for doc in snap!.documents {
            let date = doc["createdOn"] as! Timestamp
            print(formatter.string(from: date.dateValue()))
        }
    }
```

In the firebase I configured that datefield value as Sun Jan 26, 2020 12:00 AM UTC +5:30.

My question is regardless of time zone, I want the date string result to be **Sun Jan 26, 2020**, how can I achieve this

Answer (score -1):

Firestore timestamps don't have a sense of local timezone.  What you see in the Firebase console is the timestamp interpreted in the timezone configured on the local machine.  It will appear differently when viewed from different timezones, but the point in time represented by the timestamp always remains the same.  Internally, timestamps use UTC.  From the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp):

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or
>   calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
>   nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time. It is encoded using the
>   Proleptic Gregorian Calendar which extends the Gregorian calendar
>   backwards to year one. It is encoded assuming all minutes are 60
>   seconds long, i.e. leap seconds are “smeared” so that no leap second
>   table is needed for interpretation. Range is from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
>   to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z. By restricting to that range, we
>   ensure that we can convert to and from RFC 3339 date strings.

If you want to format the time according to a specific local timezone, you will have to make use of some library to help you with this.  The timestamp object itself will not accomodate your local time formatting needs.

Comment: I understand that  firebase console  timestamp will appear differently when viewed from different timezones. My scenario is I am configuring event which is going to happen on Jan 26, if I read that from firebase using Swift and display it on iPhone UI I see Jan 26 in Indian timezone, but My friend in  Pago Pago - American Samoa(GMT-11) time Zone sees as Jan 25 in his iPhone, how do I use the DateFormatter to correctly display the date

Comment: You might want to consider not using a timestamp at all, and instead using a different representation of a day without time, such as YYYYMMDD.